# Trying to print list element after reading each line for a string

Tags: python, list, indexing, element

I have a file which I have successfully being read into a list, I have a loop that reads through each line of that list looking for a variable called `customerID` which is just a string of 4 numbers.

I'm trying to have the if statement print the index of the list that the `customer ID` was found on, as well as the contents of that line (index).

```
def searchAccount(yourID):

    global idLocation
    global customerlist
    with open("customers.txt", "r") as f:
        customerlist = [line.strip() for line in f]


    IDExists = False
    for line in customerlist: 
        if yourID in line: 
           IDExists = True 

           break

        else: 
            IDExists = False 

    if IDExists == True: 
        print(customerlist.index(yourID))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about looping with an index, and using the index to track where you found the id?

```py
def searchAccount(yourID):

    global idLocation # What's this for?
    global customerlist
    with open("customers.txt", "r") as f:
        customerlist = [line.strip() for line in f]


    index = -1
    for i in range(len(customerlist)): 
        if yourID in customerlist[i]: 
           index = i
           break

    if index > -1:
        print('Index was {}'.format(i))
        print(customerlist[i])
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `range(len(customerlist))` and then `customerlist[i]` to get a line, you can use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to get the index of a line and the line itself.

```
def search_account(your_id):
    with open("customers.txt") as txt:
        for i, line in enumerate(txt):
            if your_id in line.strip():
                print(i, line)
                break
```

Comment: Hey that's neat :)